# Summation of functions

Tags: functions, summation

I want to define a function that is a sum of other functions. For this, I define functions of the form

```
MyFunc[A_, B_, C_, 1] = 3 x - 2 y;
MyFunc[A_, B_, C_, 2] = 8 x - 4 y;
```

And I define the the new function (which I still want to depend on the parameters A, B, C) to be the sum of the previous two:

```
NewFunc[A_, B_, C_] = Sum[MyFunc[A, B, C, i], {i, 1, 2}]
```

But this doesn't work. What is the reason and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `SetDelayed (:=)` instead of `Set (=)`, i.e., `NewFunc[a_, b_, c_] := Sum[MyFunc[a, b, c, i], {i, 1, 2}]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Functions should be defined as follows:

```
MyFunc[A_, B_, C_, 1] := 3 x - 2 y;
MyFunc[A_, B_, C_, 2] := 8 x - 4 y;
```

Then

```
NewFunc[A_, B_, C_] := Sum[MyFunc[A, B, C, i], {i, 1, 2}]
```

evaluates properly.

```
NewFunc[1, 1, 1]
(* 11 x - 6 y *)
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I get the error:
SetDelayed::write: "Tag Plus in (11\ x-6\ y)[A_,B_,C_] is Protected. "

Comment: I just reran the code, and it produced the same results without error.  I suggest you restart Mathematica, copy the code from the Answer, and try again.